# How to add a prefix to citations and references numbers in latex?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I am looking to add a prefix, say P to the reference list, so:

(1) the list will appear like

> References
>
> [P1] ...
>
> [P2] ..

(2) when I cite them they appear as  [P1] also.

I added the following to the preamble

```
\makeatletter

\def\@biblabel#1{[P#1]}

\makeatother
```

but this achieves the first requirement, not the second. So now when I cite the citation still appears as [1].

How to remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you really using `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? `\def\@biblabel#1{[P#1]}` should not work in that case. You would use refcontexts and `labelprefix` with `biblatex`.

Comment: Assuming you're actually using BibTeX, not biblatex, which bibliography style do you employ? Do you load a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This solution works only with older version (3.4) of `biblatex`***

I think that you are looking for the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{lamport1994latex,
    title={LATEX: a document preparation system: user's guide and reference manual},
    author={Lamport, Leslie},
    year={1994},
    publisher={Addison-wesley}
  }
  @book{mittelbach2004latex,
    title={The LATEX companion},
    author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel and Braams, Johannes and Carlisle, David and Rowley, Chris},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\cite{lamport1994latex} is the one we started our journey with. Then
we also got~\cite{mittelbach2004latex}.  Both
\cite{lamport1994latex,mittelbach2004latex} are good ones.

\printbibliography[prefixnumbers=P]

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

For details, please see page 76 of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: With newer versions of `biblatex` `prefixnumbers` has been renamed to `labelprefix`, the option can now only be used from a  refcontext command. Your answer only works with outdated version of the software.

Comment: The fact that `\def\@biblabel#1{[P#1]}` solved one part of the problem shows that the OP can't be using `biblatex`. With `biblatex`, `\def\@biblabel#1{[P#1]}` does nothing.

Comment: @moewe Sorry, did not note that. Actually, without a MWE, we can only make educated guesses, we can only presume and sometimes we can only conclude about the real scenario. And the askers seem to be real misers when putting their own codes in questions. They do not understand that they need to help us helping them. May be with this answer, the OP will decide switching to `biblatex`.

Comment: Yes we are all guessing. But the problem with this answer is that it only works for outdated versions of `biblatex`. I wouldn't have complained otherwise, for the current version 3.7, however, this answer is practically useless.

Comment: @moewe I understand your point. In my machine (Ubuntu 16.04, updated regularly), version of `biblatex` is 3.4. Anyway, I am going to manually update the package and then edit my answer.

Comment: It is a well-'loved' feature that Ubuntu and other Linux systems often ship stable (i.e. older or outdated) TeX live versions in their package repositories. If you want to live on the cutting edge, go with a vanilla TeX live (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092/35864). Manually updating certain packages risks version incompatibilities. (Certainly between `biblatex` and Biber, likely with custom `biblatex` styles, maybe with other packages as well.)

Comment: @moewe With my other tasks, which are more pressing at this moment, it will mean a bit too much for me to carry out the LaTeX system upgrade. Would it be possible for you to post a solution based on the latest version of `biblatex`. Thanks. I have put the necessary warning in my solution.

Answer (score 9):

With current versions of `biblatex`, you need to use `refcontext`s for `labelprefix`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{lamport1994latex,
    title={LATEX: a document preparation system: user's guide and reference manual},
    author={Lamport, Leslie},
    year={1994},
    publisher={Addison-wesley}
  }
  @book{mittelbach2004latex,
    title={The LATEX companion},
    author={Mittelbach, Frank and Goossens, Michel and Braams, Johannes and Carlisle, David and Rowley, Chris},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Addison-Wesley Professional}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]

\cite{lamport1994latex} is the one we started our journey with. Then
we also got~\cite{mittelbach2004latex}.  Both
\cite{lamport1994latex,mittelbach2004latex} are good ones.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```