# Bibliography numbering names

Tags: bibliographies, numbering

How to make bibliography numbering with different number names (easiest way please)

```
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\renewcommand\bibname{Akty prawne} 
\input{bib/akt} %Bibliography1

\renewcommand\bibname{Normy}
\input{bib/nor} %Bibliography2

\end{document}
```

Output is only [1], [2] ... and i want this below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I believe you want something that is similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389083.

Comment: It is unclear to me how you want to distinguish/assign the two prefixes.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is (almost) what you want -- tested on [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/). I was *not* able to figure out how to **restart the numbering for each `labelprefix`** .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key1,
  author = {Author1, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title1},
  publisher = {Publisher1},
  annotation = {CategotyA},
}
@book{key2,
  author = {Author2, A.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Title2},
  publisher = {Publisher2},
  annotation = {CategotyB},
}
\end{filecontents}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333682
\defbibcheck{CategotyA}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{CategotyA}{}{\skipentry}}
\defbibcheck{CategotyB}{\iffieldequalstr{annotation}{CategotyB}{}{\skipentry}}

\begin{document}

\cite{key1} \cite{key2}

% https://users.pfw.edu/nguyent/leisure.html
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389083
\newrefcontext[labelprefix = A]
\printbibliography[check=CategotyA, title = {Categoty A}]

\newrefcontext[labelprefix = B]
\printbibliography[check=CategotyB, title = {Categoty B}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Used References

- [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407)
- https://users.pfw.edu/nguyent/leisure.html
- [How to add a prefix to citations and references numbers in latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389083)
- [biblatex filter on arbitrary field](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333682)