# Two reference lists with custom citation numbers

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I require two citation lists with the following format...

1. Main report reference list

[1] [2] [3] etc

2. Appendix References

[A1] [A2] [A3] etc

I have approx. 50 different references which are cited throughout the report.

I currently use these lines of code to produce two reference lists...

```
\printbibliography[keyword={MainRep},notkeyword={Appendix},title={Main Report References}] 
\printbibliography[keyword={Appendix},notkeyword={MainRep},title={Appendix References}]
```

How can I change the citation numbering format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set a new `refcontext` with the [`labelprefix` key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389228/106162) to add prefix numbers.

However, it sounds like you also want to set a new `refsection` to avoid having to set `keywords` in your bib entries to filter the `\printbibliography` statements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\section{Main}
\cite{aksin}

\printbibliography

\newrefsection

\section{Appendix}
\cite{angenendt}

\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Compiled code showing separate main and appendix bibliographies featuring only citations made in the respective section. The appendix citations are prefixed by the letter A]

Or if both bibliographies should go after the appendix use

```
\printbibliography[section=0]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=A]
\printbibliography[section=1]
```

Comment: Hi Dai, thanks for this. Unfortunately all my references are cited in a random order within my 'main report', and so there is only 1 'refsection'.

My "main report refs" contains refs [1-16], [24-27], [38-40].
My "appendix refs" contains [17-23], [28-30].

Is the best solution just to use 5 'refsections' within the main report?

Comment: @Crilly ah, so I can think of your "main" and "appendix" bibliographies more like "book" and "article" references which are both used throughout but you want them to appear in distinct bibliographies with distinct labels?

Comment: I have corrected the above issue by using defernumbers=true within my biblatex preamble.

\usepackage[bankend=biber, style=ieee, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}